# Regular Expression contain

Tags: regex

I'm in need for a regex for matching strings which can be small letters or digits but must contain at least one small letter.

So for a sample input:

```
a123 b123 123c C123 aaa AAA 1234 B123 1234
```

matches would be `a123`, `b123`, `123c` and `aaa`.

I am thinking of the expression like `(\d*|[a-z]+)+`, but not exactly. this will include `1234` and also illegal which I don't want.

Comment: Please mention the length and the general format of the string to be matched.

Answer (score 6):

I assume English alphabet and 0-9 digits:

```
[a-z0-9]*[a-z][a-z0-9]*
```

As you can see:

- The string can only contain either lower case English alphabet characters (`a-z`) or `0-9` digits.
- The string must have a lower case English alphabet `[a-z]`. The rest are optional due to `*` (*0 or more* quantifier).

Comment: @fardjad: It does. When I re-read the question, the only thing I missed is that the OP requests for only lower case characters.

Comment: This will also match `11a11`, the OP might not want to match that.

Comment: @VimalStan: There is no such indication in the wording of the post.

Comment: @nhahtdh Agreed, hence the word `might` in my comment :) Just wanted to make sure the OP understands that.

Comment: it seems really simple. i don't know why i couldn't think of it.
I think there must be other criteria I forgot
but thank you for your help

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
/([a-z\d]*[a-z][a-z\d]*)/
```

Require at least one small letter, then allow for 0 or more small letters and numbers before or after it.

Answer (score 1):

how about:

```
^(?=.*[a-z])[a-z\d]+$
```

**explanation:**

```
The regular expression:

(?-imsx:^(?=.*[a-z])[a-z\d]+$)

matches as follows:

NODE                     EXPLANATION
----------------------------------------------------------------------
(?-imsx:                 group, but do not capture (case-sensitive)
                         (with ^ and $ matching normally) (with . not
                         matching \n) (matching whitespace and #
                         normally):
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  ^                        the beginning of the string
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?=                      look ahead to see if there is:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    .*                       any character except \n (0 or more times
                             (matching the most amount possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    [a-z]                    any character of: 'a' to 'z'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-ahead
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  [a-z\d]+                 any character of: 'a' to 'z', digits (0-9)
                           (1 or more times (matching the most amount
                           possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  $                        before an optional \n, and the end of the
                           string
----------------------------------------------------------------------
)                        end of grouping
----------------------------------------------------------------------
```